# What information is sent from client to the server when a SSH connection is established?

Tags: ssh, security, privacy

So let's say I'm on machine A and connect to machine B, and then from there I connect to machine C (with three different usernames). So the SSH connections are:

```
A (john) --> B (eli) --> C(bill)

john@A ~ $ ssh eli@B
eli@B  ~ $ ssh bill@C
bill@C ~ $
```

My questions are:

1. What information, other than the originating IP and port (as in `$SSH_CONNECTION` variable), is sent when a SSH connection is established?

   - For example, what information about machine A is known to machine B?
   - Is it possible for B to know that the username of the user corresponding to the current connection is `john` on machine A?
2. In the above schema, is it possible for machine C to know that the user is actually coming from machine A?

Comment: I suggest starting with `ssh -vvv user@host`, the debug messages show a lot of the information sent.

Comment: wow thanks - that's a lot of useful info. Is there a command on the server side to check what info has been actually received? The only option that I can think of is to set the log level to DEBUG3 in `sshd.config`.

Comment: You'd better *un*-demonize the server, by stopping the service then restarting it without the -D option (/usr/sbin/sshd). And, BTW, the answer to your questions are: None (except for authentication-related info), No, No.

Comment: Ah.. thanks. In the above scheme, `C` is my home machine and `B` is my work desktop (on which I'm not a superuser). `B` can connect to `C` using keys, so I was wondering if there's a way to find out if anybody else is using my key on `B` to connect to `C`, and apparently there's no way.